# Login page customized depending on client

Tags: identityserver4

I would like to make the login page know which client requested the login in order to display some client-specific branding: Otherwise the user may be confused as to why he's redirected to this foreign login page on a different domain. A client logo will help reassure him that he's still on the right track.

What would be the most reasonable approach to get at that information?

EDIT: Note that by "client" I'm referring to the client web applications on whose behalf the authentication happens - not the user's browser. All clients are under my control and so I'm using only the implicit workflow.

To make this even more clear: I have client web apps A and B, plus the identity server I. When the user comes to I on behalf of B, the B logo should appear as we're no longer on B's domain and that may be confusing without at least showing a B-related branding.

Comment: I am not that comfortable in this, but would a custom url for certain clients work? Ip's etc can easily be spoofed which can bring confusion

Comment: @Tomm I guess I could have been more clear: The client here is the "oauth client", ie. a web application - see my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Some Theory

The easiest way to get the `ClientId` from `IdSrv 4` is through a service called `IIdentityServerInteractionService` which is used in the Account Controller to get the `AuthorizationContext`. And then follow that up with the `IClientStore` service that allows you to get the client details given the `ClientId`. After you get these details then its only a matter of sending that info to the view for layout. The client model in IdSrv 4 has a LogoUri property that you can utilize to show an image at login per client.

#### Simple Example

```
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        
        if (context?.IdP != null)
            // if IdP is passed, then bypass showing the login screen
            return ExternalLogin(context.IdP, returnUrl);

        if(context != null)
        {
            var currentClient = await _clientStore.FindClientByIdAsync(context.ClientId);

            if (currentClient != null)
            {
                ViewData["ClientName"] = currentClient.ClientName;
                ViewData["LogoUri"] = currentClient.LogoUri;
            }
        }

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```