# Multiple URL's on a OpenID Connect Provider (IdentityServer4)?

Tags: networking, identityserver4, openid-connect

We are using IdentityServer4 as an OpenID Connect provider (OP) and wonder if it's possible to have multiple domain names configured. Basically we have multiple OpenID Connect (OIDC) clients which are connected to this OP, but would like to have the ability to show different URL's depending on the requesting client.

```
ClientA (https:\\clienta.foo.com) -> Authenticate request displaying https:\\id.foo.com
ClientB (https:\\clientb.bar.net) -> Authenticate request displaying https:\\id.bar.net
ClientB (https:\\awesome.app) -> Authenticate request displaying https:\\id.awesome.app
```

**Must the OP use a single domain name?**

We have had discucssions how this affects **Issuer URL** in the discovery document and the user **Subject (sub) claim** which is recommended to consists of the OP Issuer URL + an unique ID specific to our organis.ation.

Comment: Have you considered changing branding instead of URL ? I guess what you want is to alter URL thus hide OP's existance ?

Comment: Basically we need different URL’s towards the OP because different companies use our OP and therefore need their branding and doman names.

Comment: Probably can be addressed through networking related configurations (ex:- Proxy) So adding the tag. Also, IS4 supports branding for login page as I have found in this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794854/login-page-customized-depending-on-client?rq=1

Comment: Have you consider changing branding ? Also, where are you hosting your OP ? Also, does all your customers use the same user base exposed through OP ?

Comment: We have OIDC clients with multitenancy support (different themes, functionality and URLs) and depending on the current tenant a specific OP URL need to be used. Each tenant needs a own branding of the OP.